# Is there a library for detecting which RTS flags are set?

Tags: haskell, ghc

When I run `./MyProgram +RTS -N4` I want my program to automatically detect that it's running on 4 cores and create 4 sparks to process a data set.  Right now, I am recompiling every time I want to change this option, which is annoying.

Comment: May [`getNumCapabilities`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Concurrent.html#v:getNumCapabilities) be what you want?

Answer (score 2):

Answering your original question: Runtime Options are GHC-specific, and there is a module provided by GHC which allows you to see the full argument list (including `+RTS` and `-RTS`) passed to a program: [`GHC.Environment`](http://lambda.haskell.org/platform/doc/current/ghc-doc/libraries/base-4.5.1.0/GHC-Environment.html).

Here is a little demonstration:

```
import GHC.Environment (getFullArgs)
import System.Environment (getArgs)

main = do
    getFullArgs >>= mapM putStrLn
    putStrLn "=="
    getArgs >>= mapM putStrLn
    return ()
```

Compiling the program as `ghc App.hs --make -rtsopts -threaded` will result in the following when executed:

```
./App hello +RTS -N4 -RTS ook ooks
hello
+RTS
-N4
-RTS
ook
ooks
==
hello
ook
ooks
```

Comment: This method will break if there is ever a change in syntax for how to express an option.